# how to make ionic popup error message on submit

Tags: ionic-framework

I need help to make the response a popup message rather than having it display below the submit button.

template.html

```
<div class="item item-text-wrap">
                        Response: <b ng-bind="response"></b>
                    </div>
```

app.js

```
$http.post(link, {
          inputName : $scope.data.inputName

        }).then(function (res){
           $scope.response = res.data;
        });
```

app.js I wan to add this popup dialog to the response message

```
// An alert dialog
 $scope.showAlert = function() {
   var alertPopup = $ionicPopup.alert({
     title: 'Don\'t eat that!',
     template: 'It might taste good'
   });

   alertPopup.then(function(res) {
     console.log('Thank you for not eating my delicious ice cream cone');
   });
 };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

app.js

```
$http.post(link, {
  inputName : $scope.data.inputName
}).then(function (res){
  // $scope.response = res.data;
  $ionicPopup.alert({
    title: 'Success!',
    template: res.data
  });
});
```

Comment: I need to grap the date form res.data   could that look like this? template: (res.data);

Comment: do I need the brackets?